# AJAX more button in PHP to fetch more records

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How can I make the load more button working to make the LIMIT 0,5 to convert to LIMIT 0,10 and on third click it converts to LIMIT 0,15 and maximum up to LIMIT 0,30

I am using the following PHP, MySQL to fetch records from the database

```
$select_resdetails = mysql_query("SELECT *, ((ACOS( SIN( -27.486204 * PI( ) /180 ) * SIN( `store-latitude` * PI( ) /180 ) + COS( -27.486204 * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( `store-latitude` * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( (152.994962 - `store-longitude`) * PI( ) /180 ) ) *180 / PI( )) *60 * 1.1515) AS `distance` FROM ( SELECT max(if(`field_name`='store-name', `field_value`, null )) AS `store-name`,
 max(if(`field_name`='store-description', `field_value`, null )) AS `store-description`, max(if(`field_name`='store-longitude', `field_value`, null )) AS `store-longitude`, max(if(`field_name`='store-latitude', `field_value`, null )) AS `store-latitude` FROM `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` WHERE `form_name` = 'Add Store' GROUP BY `submit_time`) A  ORDER BY `distance` LIMIT 0,5");
?>
<form class="ui-filterable">
      <input id="myFilter" data-type="search">
</form>
<ul data-inset="true" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#myFilter" style="padding:0px;">
<?php 
while($fetch_resdetails = mysql_fetch_array($select_resdetails)) {
echo '<li>
        <h2>' . $fetch_resdetails['store-name'] . '</h2>
        <p>' . number_format(($fetch_resdetails['distance']), 2, '.', '') . ' KM <em>' . $fetch_resdetails['store-description'] . '</em></p>
        </a>
      </li>
';
}
?>
<input type="button" value="Load More" />
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

save the click amount in local storage

```
if(limit <= 30){
  limit = limit + 5;
  localStorage.setItem("limit", limit);
}
```

dont forget initial variable and make default value 5

And send this variable by ajax

USE THE GET METHOD
and send the parameter

```
$.get( "example.php?limit="+localStorage.getItem("limit"), 
function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
```

IN your php file use $_GET['limit'] to read limit variable

Answer (score 0):

I am using Yii framework for solving this problem.

in views file:

```
<div id="own_video_list">
<a href="javascript: void(0)" class= "load" id="'.$videos_limit.'">View more</a>
</div>
```

here $videos_limit is first limit(say 5).

in js:

```
$('#own_video_list .load').live('click', function() {
     var lastaction = $(this).attr("id");
     var type       = 'own_video_list';

     loadMoreVideos(type, lastaction);
     return false;
```

});

```
function loadMoreVideos(type, lastaction)
{
  if(lastaction)
  {
     $("#"+type+" a#"+lastaction).html('<img src = "/images/loading.gif" alt = "loading">  Loading...');
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "/videos/home/loadmorevideoshome",
        data: "type="+ type + "&lastId=" +lastaction,
        success: function(html){
           $("#"+type+" a.load").parent().parent().remove();
           $("#"+type).append(html);
           $('body').animate({scrolltop: $('body')[0].scrollHeight});
        }
     });
  }
  else
  {
     $("#"+type+" .load").html("no more video");
  }
```

}

in controller:

```
public function actionLoadmorevideoshome()
{
  $type      = $_REQUEST['type'];
  $lastId    = $_REQUEST['lastId'];
  $userId    = Yii::App()->user->getId();
  $videoHtml = '';

  $videos = VideoList::getMostRecentVideos(self::RECORD_PER_PAGE, $userId , $lastId, 1);

  if( is_array($videos) && (count($videos) > 0) )
  {
     $videoHtml  .= $this->renderPartial('_view', array(
                                         'videoList' => $videos, 'type' => $type, )
                                         , true, false);
     $lastId = $lastId + count($videos);

     $videoHtml .= '<div class="video_col_01">
                      <div style="margin-left: 20px;" class="search_btn">
                         <a href="javascript: void(0)" class= "load" id="'.$lastId.'">View more</a>

                      </div>
                   </div>';

   }
   else
   {
      $videoHtml .= '<div class="video_col_01"><font color="red">No More Video</font></div>';
   }

   echo $videoHtml;
   Yii::app()->end();
}
```

Comment: Could you narrow your code to the part that is actually fixing the problem? If all of this is necessary maybe it's not the right answer to op's problem.